# Form filter in symfony: imposible when a field is type "date"

Tags: symfony1

anyone has tried to create a symfony form filter from a class which has a field of type "date" ?

When i do it, i get this error:

> 500 | Internal Server Error |
>   Doctrine_Connection_Mysql_Exception
>   SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter
>   number: number of bound variables does
>   not match number of tokens stack trace

I think the error dependens on this command:

> 'SELECT b.id AS b__id, b.day AS b__day FROM birthday b WHERE b.day >= ? AND
>   b.day <= ?', array('month' => '1','day' => '2', 'year' => '2014')

but i dont know how can i solve it..

Any idea?

Javi

Comment: Can you provide the underlying code that generates your widget as well as the code that calls the SQL you mentioned?  It seems like you're using the 3-dropdowns date widget but the values are not getting combined into a single value properly, quite possibly because the wrong variable is being referenced when generating that SQL string.  With your code we'll be able to provide more detailed feedback.

Answer (score 0):

If you changed the filter class, be sure to use the correct widget (sfWidgetFormFilterDate) and validator (sfValidatorDateRange) (check lib/model/doctrine/base/BaseYoumodelForm.class.php for basic usage)